# Beignet OpenCL PyGPU issues

Tags: python, opencl, theano, beignet

I'm trying to use OpenCL as a backend for Theano on Kubuntu 17.04 and have run into a couple problems which I can't find my way around.

Since I am using an Intel Broadwell processor (i7-5557u if that helps any), I downloaded a copy of the Beignet source code (1.3.1) and all of its dependencies and `make && make install`ed it. Based on the [instructions](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Beignet/), this seems to have worked fine because

1. the `./utest_run` command reports 100% success
2. `clinfo` gives a whole bunch of information on the OpenCL capabilities of this processor (which I assume are correct). Prior to installing Beignet, it showed no support.

Next, I downloaded a copy of Anaconda (4.4) and added `Keras` (2.0.6), `Theano` (0.9.0), and `pygpu` (0.6.9) via the `conda` package manager. Keras and Theano seem to work fine because a python script that I've adapted from the fast.ai course does what it should when using the CPU (obviously very slowly). Additionally a simple test script taken from ye olde internet says that the CPU path works okay (https://pastebin.com/wM9jaGMF for reference).

To make Theano use the OpenCL backend, I added the `~/.theanorc` file with the following content:

`[global]
floatX = float32
device = opencl0:0`

Now when I run the above pastebin script, it gives the following error:

`ERROR (theano.gpuarray): Could not initialize pygpu, support disabled
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sahab/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gpuarray/__init__.py", line 164, in <module>
    use(config.device)
  File "/home/sahab/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gpuarray/__init__.py", line 151, in use
    init_dev(device)
  File "/home/sahab/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gpuarray/__init__.py", line 60, in init_dev
    sched=config.gpuarray.sched)
  File "pygpu/gpuarray.pyx", line 634, in pygpu.gpuarray.init
  File "pygpu/gpuarray.pyx", line 584, in pygpu.gpuarray.pygpu_init
  File "pygpu/gpuarray.pyx", line 1057, in pygpu.gpuarray.GpuContext.__cinit__
GpuArrayException: clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &nump): Unknown error`

A simpler test of

`DEVICE="opencl0:0" python -c "import pygpu; pygpu.test()"`

throws the same error as above.

I **think** the problem stems from Beignet and not pygpu, but I don't know how to track down the root problem since clinfo seems to wrok fine. I've done a fair bit of research, but it doesn't seem like this is something that people are doing as there isn't really any documentation/blog posts/whathaveyou about it. Any thoughts on this?

(For the record, I'm fairly certain that this won't give me too much of a speed boost given the computer I have available, but based on some reading, it should at least make it 1.5 to 2x faster, so it should still be worth it for me to try to track it down)

My `clinfo` output for posterity:

```
Number of platforms                               2
  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 beignet 1.3
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_spir cl_khr_icd cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_subgroups_short cl_khr_gl_sharing
  Platform Extensions function suffix             Intel

  Platform Name                                   Portable Computing Language
  Platform Vendor                                 The pocl project
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.0 pocl 0.13, LLVM 3.8.1
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             POCL

  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) Iris Graphics 6100 BroadWell U-Processor GT3
  Device Vendor                                   Intel
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 beignet 1.3
  Driver Version                                  1.3
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 beignet 1.3
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Max compute units                               48
  Max clock frequency                             1000MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     1
    Supported partition types                     None, None, None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             512x512x512
  Max work group size                             512
  Preferred work group size multiple              16
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                16 / 8       
    short                                                8 / 8       
    int                                                  4 / 4       
    long                                                 2 / 2       
    half                                                 0 / 8        (cl_khr_fp16)
    float                                                4 / 4       
    double                                               0 / 2        (n/a)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (cl_khr_fp16)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (n/a)
  Address bits                                    32, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              4294967296 (4GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           2147483648 (2GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        8192
  Global Memory cache line                        64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            65536 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Base address alignment for 2D image buffers   4096 bytes
    Pitch alignment for 2D image buffers          1 bytes
    Max 2D image size                             8192x8192 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             8192x8192x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                8
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               65536 (64KiB)
  Max constant buffer size                        134217728 (128MiB)
  Max number of constant args                     8
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Prefer user sync for interop                    Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      80ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
    SPIR versions                                 1.2
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                __cl_copy_region_align4;__cl_copy_region_align16;__cl_cpy_region_unalign_same_offset;__cl_copy_region_unalign_dst_offset;__cl_copy_region_unalign_src_offset;__cl_copy_buffer_rect;__cl_copy_image_1d_to_1d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_2d;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_2d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_3d;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_3d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_buffer;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_buffer;__cl_copy_buffer_to_image_2d;__cl_copy_buffer_to_image_3d;__cl_fill_region_unalign;__cl_fill_region_align2;__cl_fill_region_align4;__cl_fill_region_align8_2;__cl_fill_region_align8_4;__cl_fill_region_align8_8;__cl_fill_region_align8_16;__cl_fill_region_align128;__cl_fill_image_1d;__cl_fill_image_1d_array;__cl_fill_image_2d;__cl_fill_image_2d_array;__cl_fill_image_3d;
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_spir cl_khr_icd cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_subgroups_short cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_khr_fp16

  Platform Name                                   Portable Computing Language
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     pthread-Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5557U CPU @ 3.10GHz
  Device Vendor                                   GenuineIntel
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 2.0 pocl
  Driver Version                                  0.13
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 2.0
  Device Type                                     CPU, Default
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Max compute units                               4
  Max clock frequency                             3400MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     4
    Supported partition types                     equally, by counts
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             4096x4096x4096
  Max work group size                             4096
  Preferred work group size multiple              8
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                16 / 16      
    short                                                8 / 8       
    int                                                  4 / 4       
    long                                                 2 / 2       
    half                                                 8 / 8        (n/a)
    float                                                4 / 4       
    double                                               2 / 2        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              17862586368 (16.64GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           17862586368 (16.64GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Shared Virtual Memory (SVM) capabilities        (core)
    Coarse-grained buffer sharing                 Yes
    Fine-grained buffer sharing                   Yes
    Fine-grained system sharing                   No
    Atomics                                       Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Preferred alignment for atomics                 
    SVM                                           0 bytes
    Global                                        0 bytes
    Local                                         0 bytes
  Max size for global variable                    0
  Preferred total size of global vars             0
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        32768
  Global Memory cache line                        64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            1116411648 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Max 2D image size                             32768x32768 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                128
    Max number of read/write image args           <printDeviceInfo:106: get CL_DEVICE_MAX_READ_WRITE_IMAGE_ARGS : error -30>
  Max number of pipe args                         16
  Max active pipe reservations                    1
  Max pipe packet size                            1024
  Local memory type                               Global
  Local memory size                               17862586368 (16.64GiB)
  Max constant buffer size                        17862586368 (16.64GiB)
  Max number of constant args                     8
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties (on host)                      
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Queue properties (on device)                    
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Preferred size                                16384 (16KiB)
    Max size                                      262144 (256KiB)
  Max queues on device                            1
  Max events on device                            1024
  Prefer user sync for interop                    Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      1ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
    SPIR versions                                 1.2
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_spir cl_khr_int64 cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Intel Gen OCL Driver
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Success [Intel]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            Success [Intel]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              Success [POCL]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Intel Gen OCL Driver
    Device Name                                   Intel(R) Iris Graphics 6100 BroadWell U-Processor GT3
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Intel Gen OCL Driver
    Device Name                                   Intel(R) Iris Graphics 6100 BroadWell U-Processor GT3

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.2.11
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 2.1
```

Comment: Have you tried using POCL (platform 1 on your system)? If you don't get any errors when using `DEVICE="opencl1:0"` then I'd suspect Beignet.

Comment: Using `opencl1:0` has the same exact output. I tried this on macOS and even though I get past this particular hump, the vgg16 model still doesn't work (it throws exceptions: https://github.com/Theano/libgpuarray/issues/498), so I kinda just gave up on this.